# Why local directory is empty after "ADD ." on dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In my main directory :

- docker-compose.yaml
- php.Dockerfile
- foo.txt
- htmlhtml (dir)

Docker-compose.yaml content

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web-server:
    build:
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
      context: .
    #    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./htmlhtml/:/var/www/htmlhtml/"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

php.Dockerfile content

```
FROM php:7.4.3-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/htmlhtml

ADD . /var/www/htmlhtml/
```

The ADD instruction should put the file 'foo.txt' in the htmlhtml directory.

And the htmlhtml directory should be connected with the htmlhtml container's directory ?

But it doesn't.

Why ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

It does but you mount a volume on top of the directory which is presumably empty.

1. First you build the container, which will copy the files to `/var/www/htmlhtml` via the `ADD` directive
2. After that, the container is started via `docker-compose` and the volumes are mounted, in this case `./htmlhtml` is mounted to `/var/www/htmlhtml`, being an overlay to your copied files

The solution is to decide what you want. You can either

- supply the served files via a mounted volume and only copy static files, or
- copy all files to the container and use the volume for whatever you intended it to

Comment: In other words, it copies the files and then destroys them?
How to copy the files, be able to use them in the dockerfile (i.e. script.sh) and leave them after ?

Comment: No. It just mounts a directory *on top* of that directory. The contents are still there. Remove the `volume` directive in the `docker-compose.yml` and you will see the files. Alternatively, add a file to `./htmlhtml` and you will see the file appear in the container. Nothing is destroyed.